# How to make AND operation between a main and some other clipping regions?

Tags: delphi, winapi, clip

I drawing filled areas with optional holes within them in Delphi using Win API calls (polygon). The holes (not to fill them with the bg color) cut by clipping regions. It works fine until I call a print preview (and the print preview looks fine until the previewed page does not contain filled area(s) with hole(s)). The page contents in the print preview drawn by the same method call of the filledarea, just before call a paper size scaling and clipping region set on the dc. The filled area objects drawing method does not combine its own cutting operation by the page clipping one. How could make an AND operation between the page cutting clip and the other ones (the hole cutting ones should be OR related to each other).

The FilledArea object drawing method (just the clipping specific lines):

```
...
try
  if ( fHoles^.getCount > 0 ) then
  begin
    // Get a copy of the page clipping rgn
    getClipRgn( dc, rgnPrev );
    for i := 0 to fHoles^.getCount-1 do
    begin
      ...
      // create a rgn to the Xth hole
      rgn := createPolygonRgn( rgnPts^, rgnPtsCount, ALTERNATE );
      if ( rgn <> 0 ) then
      begin
        // combine the Xth rgn with the active rgn (OR because there could be many holes in a single filled area)
        extSelectClipRgn( dc, rgn, RGN_DIFF );
        // releases the Xth rgn
        deleteObject( rgn );
      end;
      ...
    end;
  end;
  //  draw the polygon
finally
  if ( fHoles^.getCount > 0 ) then
  begin
    // selects a copy of the page cutting rgn copy
    selectClipRgn( dc, rgnPrev );
    // releases the copy of the page cutting rgn
    deleteObject( rgnPrev );
  end;
end;
```

The print preview clipping region drawing code:

```
// Creates a page clipping rgn
rcRegion := createRectRgn( rcDevLeft_, rcDevTop_, rcDevRight_ + 2, rcDevBottom_ + 2 );
try
  // Selects a copy of the page clipping rgn
  selectClipRgn( dc_, rcRegion );
  ...
  // draw the page contents
  ...
finally
  // Selects an empty clipping rgn
  selectClipRgn( dc_, 0 );
  // Releases the created page clipping rgn
  deleteObject( rcRegion );
end;
```

A design time screen shot from a filled area with two holes:
[image]

A print preview screen shot from the same design (the shifted contour lines are sign that the page cutting region is ignored, the content drawn twice due to the two pages)
[image]

Comment: This is incomprehensible.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz What don't you understand?

Comment: What you are doing. A demonstrating graphic could be fine. Then again you might still need an [MCVE].

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I have inserted two pictures to demonstrate the working and the bug as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found it. I should use the combineRgn Win API call to define the Boole operations between the two incoming regions.